# Aligning li elements on top of eacher and side by side using flexbox

Tags: html, css

It is hard to explain what i exactly want so i'll post some images.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3Chg.png)
So i want the tracks to get align side by side vertically when they pass the album covers height.

li elements are dynamically generated by the js code. I created an array of objects and it passes the tracks.

Here's my html and css code. Thanks in advance im going crazy over this and it seems something so easy to do.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <title>What</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="album-container">
            <img src="" class="cover">
            <div class="album-info">
                <div class="title-info">
                    <h2 class="title">Title</h2>
                    <h3 class="artist">Playboi Carti</h3>
                    <span class="year">Year</span>
                </div>
                <ul class="tracks">
                    <!--
                    li tags gon be dynamically created by script
                    -->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btnChange">Look</button>
    </main>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=M+PLUS+Rounded+1c&display=swap');

img{
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 400px;
}


*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body{
    background-color: #0a0908;
    color: white;
    height: 100vh;
}


main{   
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-height: 400px;
}

li{
    padding: 5px;
}

.album-container{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.album-info{
    margin-left: 20px;
    flex: 1;
}


.btnChange{
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Why must the solution use flexbox?

Comment: i mean im trying to learn flexbox thats why i said flexbox but if anoter solution would be wiser to use it then i'll use that. thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not an easy problem to solve.

My suggestion would be to use a grid for the overall layout, then for the track list use an absolutely positioned nested flexbox with the following styles:

- `flex-direction: column`
- `flex-wrap: wrap`
- `align-content: start`

The absolute positioning is necessary in order to have the height of the second column be determined by the height of the image in the first column, rather than the contents of the `<ul>`.

Here is a snippet to demonstrate:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tracklist>ul').forEach(ul => {
  // get 30 random words from this API - https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/home
  fetch('https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word?number=30')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // wrap each word in an <li> tag and replace contents of <ul>
    ul.innerHTML = data.map(a => `<li>${a}</li>`).join('')
  })
})
```

```css
:root {
  --image-size: 200px;
}
body {
  margin: 1em;
}
.album {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 2em;
}
.album>img {
  width: var(--image-size);
}
.tracklist {
  position: relative;
}
.tracklist ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: start;
  gap: 0 1em;
}
hr {margin: 1em 0};
```

```html
<div class="album">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/34/400">
  <div class="tracklist">
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="album">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/64/400">
  <div class="tracklist">
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using flexbox for the `ul`, simply use the [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) property to have the list of tracks wrap into two columns.

```
ul {
    columns: 2;

    /* display: flex; */
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    /* max-height: 400px; */
}
```

```css
img{
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 400px;
}


*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body{
    background-color: #0a0908;
    color: white;
    height: 100vh;
}


main{   
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

ul{
    columns: 2;

    /* display: flex; */
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    /* max-height: 400px; */
}

li{
    padding: 5px;
}

.album-container{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.album-info{
    margin-left: 20px;
    flex: 1;
}


.btnChange{
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="album-container">
        <img src="//picsum.photos/400" class="cover">
        <div class="album-info">
            <div class="title-info">
                <h2 class="title">Title</h2>
                <h3 class="artist">Playboi Carti</h3>
                <span class="year">Year</span>
            </div>
            <ul class="tracks">
              <li>acerbically</li>
              <li>bathyscaphs</li>
              <li>covey</li>
              <li>daglock</li>
              <li>exocytosis</li>
              <li>helpless</li>
              <li>enates</li>
              <li>dopaminergic</li>
              <li>intruders</li>
              <li>rollway</li>
              <li>tamanduas</li>
              <li>butty</li>
              <li>allees</li>
              <li>atop</li>
              <li>plunkiest</li>
              <li>disloyalties</li>
              <li>ensheath</li>
              <li>precooking</li>
              <li>copywriters</li>
              <li>reifications</li>
              <li>corporeities</li>
              <li>slabbering</li>
              <li>spiritualism</li>
              <li>hyperploidies</li>
              <li>pouting</li>
              <li>leukotic</li>
              <li>hydroxylation</li>
              <li>ells</li>
              <li>remailing</li>
              <li>bevomited</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btnChange">Look</button>
</main>
```

If you want the list of tracks to flow horizontally across two columns and wrap into rows, use a two-column grid for the list of tracks.

```
ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;

    /* display: flex; */
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    /* max-height: 400px; */
}
```

```css
img{
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 400px;
}


*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body{
    background-color: #0a0908;
    color: white;
    height: 100vh;
}


main{   
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

ul{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;

    /* display: flex; */
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    /* max-height: 400px; */
}

li{
    padding: 5px;
}

.album-container{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.album-info{
    margin-left: 20px;
    flex: 1;
}


.btnChange{
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="album-container">
        <img src="//picsum.photos/400" class="cover">
        <div class="album-info">
            <div class="title-info">
                <h2 class="title">Title</h2>
                <h3 class="artist">Playboi Carti</h3>
                <span class="year">Year</span>
            </div>
            <ul class="tracks">
              <li>acerbically</li>
              <li>bathyscaphs</li>
              <li>covey</li>
              <li>daglock</li>
              <li>exocytosis</li>
              <li>helpless</li>
              <li>enates</li>
              <li>dopaminergic</li>
              <li>intruders</li>
              <li>rollway</li>
              <li>tamanduas</li>
              <li>butty</li>
              <li>allees</li>
              <li>atop</li>
              <li>plunkiest</li>
              <li>disloyalties</li>
              <li>ensheath</li>
              <li>precooking</li>
              <li>copywriters</li>
              <li>reifications</li>
              <li>corporeities</li>
              <li>slabbering</li>
              <li>spiritualism</li>
              <li>hyperploidies</li>
              <li>pouting</li>
              <li>leukotic</li>
              <li>hydroxylation</li>
              <li>ells</li>
              <li>remailing</li>
              <li>bevomited</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btnChange">Look</button>
</main>
```

Comment: Try putting the important part of the answer on Stackoverflow instead of putting it on another site behind a URL

Comment: @Ravichandra what are you talking about?